# Change on PHP7 from PHP5

Tags: php, migration, php-7

On PHP7 we know that a variable has to be inizialized with its type, differnet from where we did on php5 that the type was changed according the value set.

If we test this code

```
  <?php

  /* EAMPLE A */
  $tLisTim="";
  $i=0;
  $tLisTim[$i]=100;
  $i=$i+1;
  $tLisTim[$i]=200;

  var_dump("A");
  var_dump($tLisTim);

  /* EAMPLE B */
  $tLisTim=[];
  $i=0;
  $tLisTim[$i]=100;
  $i=$i+1;
  $tLisTim[$i]=200;

  var_dump("B");
  var_dump($tLisTim);

  ?>
```

we will get this results:

```
  PHP 5.6

  string 'A' (length=1)
  array (size=2)
    0 => int 100
    1 => int 200

  string 'B' (length=1)
  array (size=2)
    0 => int 100
    1 => int 200


  PHP 7.1

  string 'A' (length=1)
  string '12' (length=2)

  string 'B' (length=1)
  array (size=2)
    0 => int 100
    1 => int 200
```

The problem is that in PHP7 there is not warning to help us to migrate correctly all this differences.

How can I detect when we try to use a variable with an incorrect type ?

Thanks,

Comment: I would say `is_*` where * is the type you would expect ? like http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php. But to be honest why do you have in your code an empty string and expect to change it into array ?

Comment: These are probably either notices or warnings, so may not throw an error depending on your error suppressions. Try enabling warning/notice errors in your test environment while migrating to php7.

Comment: Weird, that discrepancy appears to have been introduced in PHP >= 7.1 specifically

Comment: @aynber I have all errors and notices enabled and I don't get any messages

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ah, good to know. It was a guess, since it wasn't something I had run into before.

Comment: @aynber You can check out my answer for more info

Answer (score 1):

There is no warning because PHP 7.1 did not remove support for your code structure:

> String modification by character on an empty string now works like for non-empty strings, i.e. writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces, where non-integer types are converted to integer, and only the first character of the assigned string is used. Formerly, empty strings where silently treated like an empty array.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.empty-string-modifcation-by-character

**This is still perfectly valid:**

```
$tLisTim="";
$tLisTim[0]=100;
$tLisTim[1]=200;
```

but it behaves differently than before.

Instead of silently converting to an array it sets the first position of the string to `1` and the second position to `2`.

**This will throw an error:**

```
$tLisTim="";
$tLisTim[]=100;
```

**This will throw a warning:**

```
$tLisTim="";
$tLisTim['g']=100;
```